# Deciding on power to use for box-cox transformation

Tags: data-transformation

In R, I am using the `bc` function to do a box-cox transformation. What factors do I need to consider when setting `p` (the power argument)?

Comment: The answer varies according to your reason for considering the transformation: whether it is for exploratory or confirmatory purposes, whether it is a dependent or independent variable in a regression, and so on.  Could you perhaps share some of that relevant information with us so we can give you appropriate, focused answers?

Comment: It's for exploratory purposes. I'd like to transform certain measures of an event into a comparable space for clustering (euclidean distance perhaps?). In order to get a roughly normal distribution in order to use `scale` to get standard scores, I'm transforming these measures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that I can use the following to get a transformation that best approximates a normal distribution:

```
library(geoR)
bc(x=vecToTransform, p=boxcoxfit(y)$lambda)
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is on a single variable, a likelihood profile wrt `p` is typically used, as in [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Example). Note that you need to use the right scale with geometric means of your variable and such for it to make sense.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "Note that you need to use the right scale with geometric means of your variable and such for it to make sense." How can I implement this?

Comment: Box-Cox transformation is not just $x^\lambda$, it is $\lambda\frac{x^\lambda - 1}{\dot x^{\lambda-1}}$ where $\dot x$ is the geometric mean. The reason for introducing this geometric mean is to provide correct likelihood ratio tests.

Comment: @StasK: Can you provide a reference for your claim?